# /boot running out of space when updating. What now?

Tags: centos, compression, software-updates

I just ran into a serious problem

I need to update offline CentOS boxes with fix partition sizes.
When updating the process terminates with an error that /boot need 32mb more in order to update.
It is dimensioned to 512mb. After updating are 171mb in use.
So it seems the update places temporary files and folders in /boot which are removed on finish.

**I cannot change the /boot size as some boxes are in the field.**
The update process has not been defined yet but may include updates via imaging.
But that will be some when in the future...maybe.

Is it possible to change the temporary path for /boot?
I was also wondering if it would be possible to temporarily extend the /boot size by appending a ramdisk. But how would I be able to control the process to make sure the data are on /boot only?
Compressing the temporary data on /boot through pipe in and then pipe out when used?

A closer look on how the update moves around files would be helpful.

Does anyone have another idea have to achieve an update without touching the /boot size?

Comment: Which version of CentOS? Is `/boot` an EFI partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free space by removing old kernels (keep last two):

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2
```

Comment: Good advice :)
I got in touch with a former colleague and he told me too to checkout the count of kernels.

Cheers mate